# How to login/authenticate web URL using ansible playbook with Username and password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, ansible

I am pretty new to the Ansible playbook and I am trying to log in to the website URL using username and password. I am facing the issue. I am using below code snippet. it would be great if someone could help me to achieve it.

**Code:**

```
     - name: Getting the WP Password
       ansible.builtin.shell: grep -oP '(?<=\bWPPASS=)[^;]+' config.conf
       args:
         chdir: /home/admin/golden/configuration/scripts/conf/
       register: password

     - name: Printing the WP Admin Password
       debug: msg="WPPassword={{password.stdout}}" 
     
     - name: Login to the website url
       uri:
         url: https://{{result.stdout}}.{{ domain }}/wp-admin
         method: POST
         body:
            user: admin
            password: "{{password.stdout}}"
            enter: Sign in
         status_code: 200
```

**What I am trying:**

I am trying to login to WordPress wp-admin with username and password

**what I expect**

If I provide URL, username, and password it should log in and provide a 200 status code

**Error Message**

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
fatal: [ok-example.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: can't concat str to bytes", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "https://dev.example.com/wp-admin"}
```

**Any alternate solutions are also appreciated**

Thanks

Comment: @Panki I have updated the question with an error message I am getting..hope it will give some info